# How to add number to each item in list?

Tags: python

I want to add automatic number to each item in the list using for :

```
name = ['name1','name2','name3']
```

at the end that what i want to look like:

```
1. name1
2. name2
3. name3
```

the code that i write:

```
Number = [1, 2, 3]
Name = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
for EachNumber in Number:
  for EachName in Name:
    print(EachNumber,EachName)
```

Which outputs

```
1 name1
1 name2
1 name3
2 name1
2 name2
2 name3
3 name1
3 name2
3 name3
```

Comment: If you need to add additional information to your question then you should [edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/204922) your original question, instead of using comments.

Comment: Use enumerate with start=1

Comment: Away from my PC at the moment, but maybe try enumerate(name) to start, which should result in tuples (0, name1), then a for loop to iterate over the results to print them in the format that you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use enumerate for this quite simply as -

```
l = ['name1','name2','name3']
for i in enumerate(l):
    print(i[0]+1,'-', i[1])
```

```
1 - name1
2 - name2
3 - name3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate`, with an second argument of `1` to make it start at 1 rather than 0, and then combine the index and value into a string.

```
name = [f'{i}. {val}' for i, val in enumerate(name, 1)]
```

This gives:

```
['1. name1', '2. name2', '3. name3']
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate in parallel, you'll want to use the `zip` function:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
for number, name in zip(numbers, names):
  print(number, name)
```

Which will output:

```
1 name1
2 name2
3 name3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate in loop

```
names = ['name','name','name']

for index,name in enumerate(names):

  names[index] = f'{name}{index+1}'


print(names)
```

Output:

```
['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```